# Calculate cost to combine subsets to get original set

Tags: python, algorithm, set

I have a list of items say

> [1,2,3]

and I have dictionary of some subset of the above list with a particular cost for eg.

```
{
(1) : 5.0,
(2) : 3.0,
(3) : 2.5, 
(1,3) : 6.0,
(2,3) : 5.0,
}
```

I have to find a way to get the above list with a minimum cost. For eg. I can get[1,2,3] by `combining (1),(2),(3) with a cost of 10.5,` `combining (1,3) and (2) with a cost of 9.0` and `combining (1) and (2,3) with a cost of 10.0`. With my second choice I will be able to get to the minimum cost.

I solution I can think of is to do a set partitioning of the above list [1,2,3] and match if a particular combination of subsets are present in the dictionary. But this solution is not optimal as their is a huge cost associated with generating the set partitioning of the list.

[see this link for ref.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/finding-all-k-subset-partitions) for set partitioning algorithm

Comment: Isn't this the NP-hard Minimal Set Cover optimization problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: At least, Set Cover can be reduced to this problem by giving each subset the same weight, which implies it is NP-hard.

Answer (score 0):

TrY:

- Discard from the dict any set of two items having a cost >= the cost of each individual item.
- Discard from the dict, any set of three items whose cost is >= the cost of some combination of sets of size > 3.
- ...

Greedy algorithm bit:

- Randomly select one of the remaining dicts sets of largest size
- Repeatedly add to this the largest set remaining that both

  1. covers the most remaining items of the target set,
  2. *and then*, has the least cost.

The above should give something better than a purely random selection.